# Navigate between views Sencha touch

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-touch

i'm developing an application using Sencha touch. i have implemented a sliding menu, and on tap on a menu i want to navigate to another view.

Here is the code of my controller:

```
Ext
        .define(
                'MyApp.controller.Home',
                {
                    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
                    requires : [ "MyApp.view.MovieDetails",
                            "Ext.util.InputBlocker" ],

                    config : {
                        refs : {
                            main : 'mainmenuview',
                            loginView : 'loginview',
                            inprogress:'inprogress'
                        },

                        control : {

                            'movieslistview > toolbar > button' : {
                                tap : function() {
                                    Ext.Viewport.toggleMenu("left");
                                }
                            },
                            getSlideLeftTransition : function() {
                                return {
                                    type : 'slide',
                                    direction : 'left'
                                };
                            },

                            'menu > button' : {
                                tap : function(btn) {
                                    var me = this;
                                    var newActiveItem = Ext.ComponentQuery
                                            .query("movieslistview[menu="
                                                    + btn.getMenu() + "]"), main = this
                                            .getMain();

                                    newActiveItem = newActiveItem.length > 0 ? newActiveItem[0]
                                            : null;
                                    if (newActiveItem) {
                                        main.setActiveItem(newActiveItem);
                                        Ext.Viewport.hideAllMenus();
                                        if (btn.getMenu() == "inprogress") {
                                            inprogress = me.getInprogress();
                                            Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(inprogress, me.getSlideLeftTransition());

                                        }   

                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            'moviedetails' : {
                                swipe : function(moviedetails, e) {
                                    var target = Ext.fly(e.target);
                                    if (target.findParent(
                                            '.x-scroll-container', 10, true))
                                        return;
                                    if (e.direction === "up") {
                                        moviedetails.hide();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            'moviedetails > button[action="close"]' : {
                                tap : function(button) {
                                    var details = button.up("moviedetails");
                                    details.hide();
                                    Ext.util.InputBlocker.unblockInputs();
                                }
                            },
                            'movieslistview > list' : {
                                itemtap : function(list, index, item, record,
                                        event) {
                                    this._movieDetails = this.getMovieDetails();
                                    this._movieDetails.setRecord(record);
                                    Ext.Viewport.add(this._movieDetails);
                                    Ext.util.InputBlocker.blockInputs();

                                    this._movieDetails.on({
                                        show : {
                                            fn : function() {
                                                list.deselectAll(true);
                                            },
                                            scope : this,
                                            single : true
                                        }
                                    });

                                    this._movieDetails.show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },


                    getMovieDetails : function() {
                        if (!this._movieDetails) {
                            this._movieDetails = Ext
                                    .create("Ersal.view.MovieDetails");
                        }
                        return this._movieDetails;
                    }
                });
```

The problem is here:

```
if (btn.getMenu() == "inprogress") {
                                                inprogress = me.getInprogress();
                                                Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(inprogress, me
                                                        .getSlideLeftTransition());

                                            }
```

I want to show the view "Inprogress.js" when toping on the menu "inprogress"

Thank you

Comment: This is about Sencha, not Worklight; don't use the Worklight tag if you're not asking about Worklight **features**. Consult with the Sencha forums for sencha tag.

Comment: That's because i'm using sencha to develop a worklight app

Comment: The problem is in sencha, not worklight. sencha is not a worklight feature.

Comment: Ok, got it. Can you help me solving my problem with sencha plz